# CGColor and UIDeviceRGBColor leaks

Tags: swift

I have a weird problem - the Xcode issue navigator reports that my app leaks CGColor and UIDeviceRGBColor.

The class in which this occurs seems fairly simple to me, but hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

```
import Foundation

internal enum TriangleDirection {
    case up
    case down
}

class TriangleView: UIView {
    let size: CGFloat = 12.0
    var direction: TriangleDirection = .up
    var colour = UIColor(red: 1.000, green: 1.000, blue: 1.000, alpha:     0.7)

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        myInit()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        myInit()
    }

    func myInit() {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    // change to up or down
    func set(direction: TriangleDirection, colour: UIColor = UIColor(red: 1.000, green: 1.000, blue: 1.000, alpha: 0.7)) {
        self.direction = direction
        self.colour = colour
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // general declarations
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        let origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

        // draw triangle
        context!.saveGState()
        context!.translateBy(x: origin.x, y: origin.y)
        let trianglePath = UIBezierPath()

        // draw depending on direction...
        if direction == .up {
            trianglePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: size/2, y: 0))
            trianglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: size, y: (size * 0.8)))
            trianglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: (size * 0.8)))
        } else {
            trianglePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: size/2, y: (size * 0.8)))
            trianglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
            trianglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: size, y: 0))
        }

        trianglePath.close()
        colour.setFill()
        trianglePath.fill()

        context!.restoreGState()
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
    }
}
```

[Issue Navigator warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWqDR.png)